# Is there a way to execute SQL Update command through asp:HyperLink click (vb.net)?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink

I have a Hyperlink inside a Repeater which gets its NavigateUrl dynamically from code behind and opens a popup(lightbox) window with iframe content inside.

I need to execute SQL Update Command when that Hyperlink is clicked. Problem is that I can't (or don't know how to) use a LinkButton and its onClick event because of postback and popup window problem. Is there a way to do this somehow?

Comment: Why don't you do what you need to do in the Page_Load of the page being loaded in the iFrame?

Comment: To avoid post back you could setup the code in the onClick as a web service and then call that service from javascript.

Comment: iFrame content is on the other server which I don't have access to.

Comment: So you want to do something when a user clicks a hyperlink in your iFrame? It sounds like it's dependent on the implementation of the other page, but maybe you can inject javascript into the iFrame that would make the call to your server. I can't see a way to do it without altering the iFrame HTML.

Comment: No, I have to update a table from database on my server, data in a Repeater where's my Hyperlink is provided from that table. Simply I need to update a table when Hyperlink is clicked. Sorry for my bad english.